# rails 3 polymorphic association with paperclip and multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, polymorphic-associations

I want to make polymorphic associations with paperclip, and allow my user to have one avatar and multiple images.

**Attachment** model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Avatar < Attachment
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => "150x150>", :view => "260x180>" },
end

class Image < Attachment
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => "150x150>", :view => "260x180>" },
end
```

User Model:

```
has_one :avatar, :as => :attachable, :class_name => 'Attachment', :conditions => {:type => 'avatar'}
accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar
```

User Controller:

```
def edit
   @user.build_avatar
end
```

User View form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :avatar do |asset| %>
      <% if asset.object.new_record? %>
          <%= asset.file_field :image %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

when I attempt to save the changes I get the error => unknown attribute: avatar

if I remove the :class_name => 'attachment' in the has_one association I get the error =>
uninitialized constant User::Avatar

I need to also attach avatars to blog posts, so I need the association to be polymorphic (or atleast i think so)

I am stumped and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do have a project in the works that is successfully using Paperclip and polymorphic associations. Let me show you what I have, and maybe you can apply it to your project:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :artwork, :as => :artable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artwork
  ...
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :artwork, :as => :artable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artwork
  ...
end

class Artwork < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :artwork_content_type, :artwork_file_name, :artwork_file_size, :artwork

  # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :artwork,
    :styles => {
      :small => "100",
      :full => "400"
    }

  validates_attachment_content_type :artwork, :content_type => 'image/jpeg'
end
```

the songs form and the albums form include this as a partial:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.fields_for :artwork do |artwork_fields| %>
  <%= artwork_fields.label :artwork %><br />
  <%= artwork_fields.file_field :artwork %>
<% end %>
```

don't forget to include :html => { :multipart => true } with the form

artworks_controller.rb

```
class ArtworksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @artwork = Artwork.new(params[:artwork])

    if @artwork.save
        redirect_to @artwork.artable, notice: 'Artwork was successfully created.'
    else
        redirect_to @artwork.artable, notice: 'An error ocurred.'
    end
  end
end
```

and finally, an excerpt from songs_controller.rb:

```
def new
    @song = Song.new
    @song.build_artwork
end
```

Comment: @kaigth, sorry I gave you such a runaround. I should have just started with this. Best wishes.

Comment: can the styles for attachments in Artwork model be different for Album and song based on polymorphic relation?

Comment: @RamkumarMK I believe your models would all share the same artwork style. So in that one location you should define all of the styles any model needs, or else reconsider whether or not you need to be using a polymorphic association vs something unique to each case

Comment: @Brett in mycase,the artwork style has to be different across models . [this](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/45-use-sti-and-polymorphic-model-for-multiple-uploads) article recommends sti and polymorphic combination solution, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really need to be polymorphic. How about this approach, which uses has_many :through? In plain English, the user has one avatar which has multiple images, and through this association you can call User.images to get the collection of images associated with the avatar.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar
  has_many :images, :through => :avatar
end

class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :avatar
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => "150x150>", :view => "260x180>" },
end
```

Having said all of this, I am left to wonder why you need to go through all this anyway. Why not just do

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :avatars
end
```

which would give you as many images (avatars) as you want.

Comment: thats awesome, but I also want to attach avatars to blog posts, so I would still need to use polymorphic associations Post::Avatar

Comment: @kaigth would you not want to attach users to blog posts, and then grab their associated avatar?

Comment: @ Brett I want people to be able to assign seperate avatars for blog posts, so their posts can be unique instead of a users avatar

Comment: Also I will be adding images later to other models, and this is why I need it to be polymorphic.