# Polymorphic association and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I have a Product model and an Image model (based on paperclip).

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable,
                    dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :picture
end
```

I want to add image for my products in the same page I create product (`/products/new`). Here is the form :

```rb
<%= form_for(@product, html: { multipart: true}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :name, t('product.name') %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>                    
  <div class="file_field">
     <%= f.fields_for :image do |images_form| %>
       <%= images_form.file_field :image %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit @submit_button %>
<% end %>
```

Then I go to the `/products/new` page, I fill in the fields, and click on the submit button. The server try to renders the product's show page, but it doesn't work because the image has not been saved. I have the following error :

```rb
undefined method `picture' for nil:NilClass
```

for the following line in the product's show page

```rb
image_tag(@product.images.first.picture.url(:medium))
```

I wonder why the image has not be saved and I see that the server renders the following message :

```rb
Unpermitted parameters: images_attributes
```

So I added image attributes in the permit products params ([like there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606753/rails-3-polymorphic-association-with-paperclip-and-multiple-models)) :

```rb
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :sharable, :givable, image_attributes: [:name, :picture_file_name, :picture_content_type, :picture_file_size])
end
```

But it doesn't change anything, I always have the same error message. Do you have an idea where does the permission issue come from ?

Comment: `params.require(:product).permit(:name, :sharable, :givable, image_attributes: [:name, :picture_file_name, :picture_content_type, :picture_file_size])` to `params.require(:product).permit(:name, :sharable, :givable, :image)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to change

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :sharable, :givable, image_attributes: [:name, :picture_file_name, :picture_content_type, :picture_file_size])
```

to

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :sharable, :givable, images_attributes: [:name, :picture])
```

Comment: Oh no ! I have mistaken. When I restarted the server, the product's show page rendered good, but the image was not saved anymore. `#<Image id: 3, name: nil, imageable_id: 249, imageable_type: "Product", picture_file_name: nil, picture_content_type: nil, picture_file_size: nil, picture_updated_at: nil, created_at: "2013-08-25 13:48:56", updated_at: "2013-08-25 13:48:56">]>`

Comment: Ok, Could you please update the info in your question to match the current state (last version of the code, errors thrown, etc)

Comment: Ok, I found it ! I replaced `:picture_file_name, :picture_content_type, :picture_file_size` by `:picture` in the permitted attributes, and it works now just fine. Do you want to update your answer ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer validation Flo Rahl. Team work on this one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You define a has_many association, so in your view, it should be f.fields_for :images

```
<%= f.fields_for :images do |images_form| %>
    <div class="file_field">         
       <%= images_form.file_field :picture %>         
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In your controller, you should build some images first and add your images_attributes to permitted parameters.

```
@product = Product.new
3.times {@product.images.build}
```

your view will show 3 file fields.

Comment: It doesn't work, I always have the "Unpermitted parameters: images_attributes" message.

Comment: you need change image_attributes to images_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Any chance this has to do with your `file_field` being

```
<%= images_form.file_field :image %>
```

instead of the following?

```
<%= images_form.file_field :picture %>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I always have the "Unpermitted parameters: images_attributes" message.

Comment: Flo Rahl, Could you please add the exact error message to your question ?

Comment: Thanks, I added a new answer to keep things clear. Tell me if it helps. Thanks